Could not find any NVIDIA binaries on this host!, when i try to run docker image on server using singularity
I am trying to run a docker image on slurm server, I pulled this software's image from docker to my local machine then, copied to server.
When I run it on the server using
singularity run aoflagg.sif

It gives the following warning

INFO:    Could not find any NVIDIA binaries on this host!
The server has singularity version 3.4.1-4.2.ohpc.1.3.9
need help in what this warning is ? and how to solve this issue?

